# How to copy values from table for another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

have table with some values

```
role_number  action_number    status
   4               2            1
   4               5            0
   4               8            1
   4               7            0
   4               10           1
   4               3            0
```

Now want new role_number with same action_number and status , how to insert it ? for example it must be like  :

```
  role_number  action_number    status
       4               2            1
       4               5            0
       4               8            1
       4               7            0
       4               10           1
       4               3            0
       5               2            1
       5               5            0
       5               8            1
       5               7            0
       5               10           1
       5               3            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
    (role_number, action_number, status)
SELECT role_number + 1, action_number, status
FROM YourTable
WHERE role_number = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a possible solution using INSERT/SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(role_number, action_number, status)
SELECT @NewRoleNumber, action_number, status
FROM YourTable
WHERE RoleNumber = @RoleNumberToBeCopied
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [tablename] (role_number, action_number, status)
SELECT 5, action_number, status FROM [tablename] where role_number = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert from the same table

```
INSERT INTO TableName
SELECT MAX(role_number)+1, action_number, status FROM TableName WHERE role_number = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @oldRollNo int = 4,
        @newRollNo int = 5;
INSERT INTO tablename (role_number, action_number, status)
SELECT @newRollNo, action_number, status FROM tablename where role_number = @oldRollNo
```